# Enlarging Swiper Navigation Buttons

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm trying to enlarge the arrow of the Navigation of my swiper.

I found that it is control by this CSS ".swiper-button-next::after", which is defined in swiper.bundle.css. The relevant part is this:

```
    .swiper-button-next::after {
    font-family: swiper-icons;
    font-size: var(--swiper-navigation-size); // controls the arrow size
    text-transform: none !important;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    font-variant: initial;
    line-height: 1;
    }
```

My preferred option is to control the "swiper-navgiation-size" variable but I can't find a way to set it.

Alternatively, I tried to override these settings from my components css but I can't get access I tried:

```
::ng-deep .swiper-button-next::after {
    font-size: 150px !important;
  }
```

and

```
::after .swiper-button-next {
    font-size: 150px !important;
  }
```

But nothing works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not required any ::ng-deep or ::after

```css
.swiper-button-next {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The default swiper button size is 44px using less than/greater than fonts ('<' and '>'). The default size is located in the [root navigation scss file](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/Swiper8/src/modules/navigation/navigation.scss#L4). To increase the navigation button size, add a css file with this to override the default size:

```css
:root {
    --swiper-navigation-size: 88px;
}
```

This should double the navigation arrow size.

Answer (score 0):

```
.swiper-button-next::after{
    font-size:150px!important ;
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful with some **explanation**. Explain what it does, and how it's **different / better** than existing answers.